# Create multiple Rails servers sharing same database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backend

I have a Rails app hosted on Heroku. I have to do long backend calculations and queries against a mySQL database.

My understanding is that using DelayedJob or Whenever gems to invoke backend processes will still have impact on Rails (front-end) server performance. Therefore, I would like to set up two different Rails servers.

The first server is for front-end (responding to users' requests) as in a regular Rails app. 
The second server (also a Rails server) is for back-end queries and calculation only. It will only read from mySQL, do calculation then write results into anothers Redis server.

My sense is that not lot of Rails developers do this. They prefer running background jobs on a Rails server and adding more workers as needed. Is my sever structure a good design, or is it an overkill? Is there any pitfall I should be aware of?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there some reason the second has to be a rails app? background tasks seem good enough, that or make a ruby script and have a cron run that. Can you not do that on Heroku? sorry no knowledge on Heroku.

Comment: Hi Saifis, as I mentioned above, I think when I run cron, it will take too much resources from Rails server, and thus make responses to users' request slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason why a background job like DelayedJob would cause any more overhead on your main application than another server would.  The DelayedJob runs in it's own process so the dyno's for your main app aren't affected.  The only impact could be on the database queries but that will be the same whether from a background job or another app altogether that is accessing the same database.

I would recommend using DelayedJob and workers on your primary app.  It keeps things simple and shouldn't be any worse performance wise.

One other thing to consider if you are really worried about performance is to have a database "follower", this is effectively a second database that keeps itself up to date with your primary database but can only be used for reads (not writes).  There may be better documentation about it, but you can get the idea here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fast-database-changeovers#create_a_follower.  You could then have these lengthy background jobs read data from here leaving your main database completely unaffected.